# The lattice spanned by $m$ random 0-1 vectors of length $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-matrices, lattices

Consider $m$ random 0-1 vectors of length $n$. Let $L$ be the lattice spanned by them. What is the value of $m$ (as a function of $n$) for which it is true with positive probability that $L=Z^n$? More generally, let $V(L)$ be the rank of $Z^n/L$ (The volume of $L$). What is the behavior of $V(L)$ as a function of $n$ and $m$?

Comment: For the first question, are you holding this positive probability fixed as $n$ varies?

Comment: Will, yes e.g. what is m as a function of m so that the probability is roughly 1/2.

Comment: Too bad you aren't asking for roughly 1/4.  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511636 has some data about 0-1 matrices whose Smith Normal Form is the identity, which is roughly a fourth of all matrices for small n.  (It also kindly quotes a result of mine in another section.  Full disclosure and all that.)  It would not surprise me if n + O(loglogn) were achievable.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe (but haven't fully checked) that you can get an upper bound of $m=cn \log^2 n$ using the second moment method.  I'm including a sketched argument below.

I will assume WLOG that $m$ is even.  I will also (for now) make a parity assumption: I will assume that, modulo $2$, the sum of all $m$ vectors is equal to $(1,0,\dots,0)$.

Consider the $\binom{m}{m/2}$ vectors 
$$v_A := \sum_{j \in A} v_j - \sum_{j \notin A} v_j,$$
where $A$ is any subset of size $m/2$.  For any given $A$, the probability $v_A$ equals $(1,0,\dots  0)$ is 
$$\frac{\binom{m}{m/2-1}}{2^{m-1}} \left(\frac{\binom{m}{m/2}}{2^{m-1}}\right)^{n-1} = \left(\frac{4}{\pi n}+o(1)\right)^{n/2}$$
by Stirling's approximation (note that I'm dividing by $2^{m-1}$ here due to the parity assumption).

So the expected number of $v_A$ equal to $(1,0,\dots,0)$ is (again using Stirling's approximation)
$$\frac{2^m}{\sqrt{\pi m/2}} \left(\frac{2}{\pi n}+o(1)\right)^{n/2}, $$
which tends to infinity for $m=c n \log n$ and sufficiently large $c$.  We now look at the second moment.

If $|A \cap B|=k$, then for each coordinate (except the first, which is pretty much the same), the event $v_A(t)=v_B(t)=0$ corresponds (after a bit of rearrangement) to the pair of events 
$$\sum_{j \in A \cap B} v_j (t) = \sum_{j \in A^C \cap B^C} v_j(t)$$
$$\sum_{j \in A \cap B^C} v_j (t) = \sum_{j \in A^C \cap B} v_j(t).$$
So the probability that both occur equals 
$$\frac{\binom{2k}{k} \binom{m-2k}{m/2-k}}{2^{m-1}}.$$
We therefore have 
$$\frac{P(v_A=v_B=0)}{P(v_A=0)^2}=\left( 2^{m-1} \frac{\binom{2k}{k} \binom{m-2k}{m/2-k}}{\left(\binom{m}{m/2}\right)^2} \right)^n$$
Applying Stirling/central binomial asmyptotics again, I get that after some more algebra this becomes 
$$\left(\frac{m/4}{\sqrt{k(m/2-k)}} \left(1+O(\frac{1}{\min(k,m/2-k)})\right)\right)^n.$$

For $|k-m/4|=t\sqrt{m}$, the first fraction is $1+O\left(\frac{t^2}{m}\right)$ so for $t=o(\sqrt{\log n})$ we have 
$$\frac{P(v_A=v_B=0)}{P(v_A=0)^2}= \left(1+O(\frac{t^2}{m})\right)^n = 1+o(1).$$
[The parity assumption is necessary to make this work -- otherwise the fact that $v_A=v_B$ modulo $2$ increases the probability by a factor of $2$ for each coordinate].  I believe (but haven't gone through the full details) that it's similarly possible to bound the tails, so by Chebyshev we will almost surely have $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ by the time we get to $m=c n \log n$, under our parity conditioning.

By another second moment calculation, we know that any subset of size $2m$ vectors almost surely has a subset of size $m$ having the desired sum modulo $2$ (the second moment calculation's actually a lot simpler here -- for any $A \neq B$ the sums of $A$ and $B$ are independent!).  So by increasing $m$ to $2cn \log n$, we can remove the parity conditioning and almost surely have a sum equal to $(1,0,\dots,0)$.  Taking $\log n$ collections of this size $m$, we can almost surely hit every coordinate vector.

Effectively I lost a $\log$ in this argument when I only considered the $v_A$ instead of more general sums, and another $\log$ in the end when I considered $\log n$ disjoint collections of vectors instead of allowing the collections to interact with each other.  Both may be unncessary.

Comment: Wonderful, Kevin (but I did not carefully check either). Do you know (by heuristics or numerics perhaps) what the answer should be?

Comment: My guess (though I don't have any sort of rigorous backup) is that actually $m=O(n)$ (or even something like $n(1+o(1))$) would be enough.  The idea is that if you look at any set of $n$ vectors, they probably will be independent and therefore span some vector of the form $(a,0,0\dots,0)$.  The only way that $(1,0,\dots,0)$ would not be in the span is if there was some factor common to the $a$ from every set of $n$ vectors, and it feels like this shouldn't be too likely (akin to how over a small field an $n \times (n+k)$ matrix is not full rank  with probability exponentially small in $k$).  

Comment: By the way, I think that the above comment may tie in with what Igor said in his comment about the relation to random homology.  As I understand it the situation with the Linial-Meshulam problem is that they have found a threshold which holds for $\mathbb{Z}_p$-homology for any fixed prime $p$ (the analogue of almost-surely being non-singular over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for any fixed $p$), but the question is still open whether there might be some sort of torsion growing with $n$ (whether there might be some common factor to all the $a$ growing with $n$).  

Answer (score 3):

To get an upper bound (for the first part of the question), one can use use the estimates described in the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13008/expected-determinant-of-a-random-nxn-matrix). Then, if the volume of the quotient by the lattice generated by the first $n$ vectors is $x,$ a coupon-collector argument gives an $n + x \log x$ upper bound (one has to be a bit careful, since the expectation is not enough, one needs information about the distribution. For the second question, you want estimates on the singular values of an $m \times n$ matrix, which is a much studied subject, especially lately by Rudelson and Vershynin. You can check out Roman Vershynin's [surveys on the subject.](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/papers.html)

Comment: Igor, x is fairly huge (the determinant of an n by n random 0,1 matrix) and then your upper bound is superexponential in n. It does not look very good.

Comment: @Gil: true, but do you believe that the truth is polynomial in $n?$ If so, why?

Comment: Dear Igor, I do not know which is why I was asking. There is a vast new progress on related questions, in particular, on the behavior of random 0/1 matrices so perhaps this is either known or follows from what is known to the experts. Maybe your estimate is close to the truth; another problem is that I do not understand the coupon collector argument even without the careful part. Can you ellaborate?

Comment: @Gil: the coupon collector argument is simply that every time you generate a new vector, it projects somewhere in the quotient. For the images to cover the quotient will take time $x \log x,$ where $x$ is the size (=volume, more or less) of the quotient). Of course, this is a very crude argument, and it may be that the Rudelson-Vershynin results give a much better bound.

Comment: @Gil and by the way, I don't know if this is why you are asking, but this has a very close relationship to the homology of random complexes (a la Linial-Meshulam). I recall thinking about this once, and a good answer to your question can help treat the $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients case, if memory serves...

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is possible to use some recent closely related work of Kenneth Maples to get a much better (but probably still not quite tight) bound.  Let $C>0$ be a constant to be chosen later.  Call an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ *good* if it satisfies each of the following properties

P1. $A$ is non-singular over $\mathbb{R}$.

P2. $|det(A)|$ has at most $C \log n$ prime factors.

P3. $A$ has rank at least $n-C \log n$ over ${\mathbb F}_p$ for every prime $p$.

Here are two claims which together would imply $n+O(\log n)$ vectors are enough.

Claim 1: A random $n \times n$ $(0,1)$ matrix is good with probability $1-O\left(C^{-1}\right)$.

Claim 2: If $A$ is any fixed good matrix, augmenting $A$ by $5C \log n$ random rows with high probability leads to a matrix whose rows span ${\mathbb Z}^n$.

We first look at claim 1.  The probability P1 fails is exponentially small in $n$ (as originally shown by Kahn, Komlos, and Szemeredi).

For P2 and P3, we use the following result of Maples (Corollary 1.3 [here](http://user.math.uzh.ch/maples/maples-cokernel.pdf)): For any prime $p$, the probability that a random $n \times n$ matrix has rank $n-k$ over ${\mathbb F}_p$ is

$$p^{-k^2} \frac{\prod_{\ell=k+1}^{\infty} \left(1-p^{-\ell}\right)}{\prod_{\ell=1}^k \left(1-p^{-\ell}\right)}+O\left(e^{-cn/2}\right),$$
where both $c$ and the constant implicit in $O()$ are independent of $p$.
We can actually bound the probability above by $O\left(p^{-k^2} +e^{-cn/2}\right)$, since the ratio of products is at most $\prod_{\ell=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{-\ell})^{-1}$.  Summing over all $k$, the probability $A$ is singular over ${\mathbb F}_p$ is $O\left(\frac{1}{p} + e^{-\frac{cn}{2}}\right)$.  Summing over all $p$, the expected number of primes less than $e^{cn/4}$ dividing $|det(A)|$ is at most $\log n +O(1)$.

There can be at most $2 \log n/c$ prime factors of $|det(A)|$ larger than $e^{cn/4}$, since otherwise $|det(A)|$ would be larger than $n^{n/2}$ and violate Hadamard's bound.  So the total expected number of factors is $O(\log n)$, and the probability P2 fails is $O(1/C)$ by Markov's inequality.

For P3, we again split into small and large primes.  Applying Maples' theorem again, the probability P3 fails for a given prime less than $e^{cn/4}$ is at most $O\left(p^{-C^2 \log^2 n}+ e^{-cn/2}\right)$, and by the union bound the probability P3 fails for some small prime is small.

For large primes, we use the observation that $A$ can only have rank less than $n-k$ over ${\mathbb F}_p$ if $p^k$ divides the determinant of $A$ (e.g. because in this case we can row reduce over the integers so $k$ rows have all entries divisible by $p$, at which point we can pull a factor of $p$ out for each row).  In particular, if $C$ is sufficiently large we know from Hadamard's bound it is impossible for P1 to succeed and P3 to fail for some prime larger than $e^{cn/4}$.   This finishes Claim 1.

We now turn to Claim 2.  We first note that the for $m \geq n$ the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$ span ${\mathbb Z}^n$ if and only if the matrix with the $v_i$ as rows has full rank over ${\mathbb F}_p$ for every prime $p$ (if the volume of a cell is $V$, then $V$ divides the determinant of every $n \times n$ submatrix).  Since $A$ is good, we know that we already are full rank for all but at most $C \log n$ primes.  So it is enough to show the augmentation with high probability fixes each of those primes.  Fix any one such prime $p$.

We use the following observation (originally due to Odlyzko): Any proper subspace of ${\mathbb F}_p^n$ contains at most half of the $(0,1)$ vectors (e.g. because if you fix a column basis, whichever column is not in the basis is determined by the remaining $n-1$ columns).  It follows that so long as $v_1, \dots ,v_j$ do not already span the space,
$$P\left(v_{j+1} \notin Span(v_1, \dots v_j)  \right) \geq \frac{1}{2}.$$
By assumption P3, $A$ already had rank at least $n-C \log n$ before we added the rows.  The only way $A$ can fail to be full rank after the augmentation is if the above event occurred at least $4 C \log n$ times, an event which occurs with probability at most
$$\binom{5C \log n}{4 C \log n} 2^{-4C \log n} = 2^{(-0.39+o(1)) C \log n}.$$
Taking the union bound over all $p$ which divide $|det(A)|$, the probability we fail to be of full rank modulo some prime is at most $C \log n 2^{-(0.39+o(1)) C \log n} = Cn^{-0.39C+o(1)}$, proving Claim 2.

This bound is probably still not quite tight, especially in the handling of P3 for large $p$. One annoyance in trying to drop below $\log n$ is that if the last row of $A$ and all the rows added in the augmentation are zero (an event occurring with probability roughly $2^{-n(m-n)}$), the matrix fails to be of full rank modulo every prime.  This means just taking the union bound over all the roughly $2^{c n \log n}$ primes less than $n^{n/2}$ won't be enough if $m-n$ is much smaller than $\log n$, unless we could possibly get some handle on the event "$A$ is of full rank over  $\mathbb{R}$ but not over ${\mathbb F}_p$" for large $p$.

Answer (score 1):

When you pick n+1 vectors from Z^n according to basically any distribution, the probability they generate is heuristically (for large n)  the reciprocal of zeta(2)zeta(3), which is about 0.436...

For example, I  just did it 1000 runs of 21 vectors in Z^{20} and got the full lattice 430 times.

In other words: The answer is m=n+1 but I don't know if you could prove it.