# Expected determinant of random symmetric matrix with different Gaussian distributions of the diagonal and non-diagonal elements

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, determinants, gaussian

Consider a random matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ where the elements are  random gaussian variables. The mean and variance of the elements are different on the diagonal and the off-diagonal:

$\begin{align}
&\left<A_{ij}\right>=p &\text{and } & \text{var}(A_{ij})=\frac{1}{N}p(1-p) &\text{  if  } \,  i=j \\
&\left<A_{ij}\right>=p^2 &\text{and } &\text{var}(A_{ij})=\frac{1}{N} p^2(1-p^2) &\text{ if } \, i\neq j
\end{align}$

where $p \in (0,1)$ is some fixed paremeter. The matrix is symmetric $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$.

Now I would like to know

$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}  |\det  A|],
\end{align}$

i.e. the asymptotic behavior as $N$ becomes large. Since the variances are approaching zero for $N \rightarrow  \infty$ I assume that the expectation of the absolute value of the determinant also approaches zero.

Is there a method to determine this behavior or does someone know how to do it?

---

Edit: I attached the following figure showing the result of Carlo Beenakker (lines)

$\mathbb{E} [|\det  A|] \sim N p^{N+1}(1-p)^{N-1}+p^{N}(1-p)^N $

and results from simulations (crosses) for different $p$. They seem to fit very well.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I may ignore the fluctuations for large $N$, I can use that the average matrix $\bar{A}=E(A)$ has $N-1$ eigenvalues equal to $p(1-p)$ and one eigenvalue equal to $p(1-p)+Np^2$. The determinant then equals 
$${\rm det}\,\bar{A}=Np^{N+1}(1-p)^{N-1}+ p^N(1-p)^N.$$
Notice that it is positive definite. It decays exponentially $\propto e^{-\alpha N}$ with exponent $\alpha=-\ln p-\ln(1-p)$.

To assess the effect of the fluctuations I might consider the matrix $\delta A=A-\bar{A}$, where the matrix elements have zero average. The eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ of $\delta A$ are distributed according to the Wigner semicircle in the interval $|\lambda|<2p(1-p)$. That determinant can be at most $2^{-N}$ in absolute value, which also decays exponentially.

---

Update, following *esg* 's answer:

For $p\lesssim 1/2$ the Hermite polynomial formula (blue, absolute value of *esg* 's answer$^*$) is not far from ${\rm det}\,\bar{A}$ (gold, above formula), see the plot for $p=0.4$ (at left) and for $p=0.05$ (at right):

[image]
[image]

For $p>1/2$ the Hermite polynomial formula decays less rapidly, but still exponentially: plots for $p=0.7$ (at left) and for $p=0.95$ (at right). The difference from the exponent $\alpha$ given above is close to a factor 1/2 for $p$ approaching 1 (compare with green curve $\propto (1-p)^{N/2}$).

[image]
[image]

In summary, based on this comparison I would conclude that the exponential decay of $\mathbb{E}\,({\rm det}\,A)$ crosses over from $\propto p^N$ for $p$ near 0 to $\propto(1-p)^{N/2}$ for $p$ near 1.

---

<sub>$^*$ I plotted the absolute value of the Hermite formula. It oscillates around zero with increasing $p$, here is for example a plot for $N=100$.</sub> 
[image]

Comment: I compared the results for the average matrix without fluctuations with numerical results for the average absolute value of the determinant of A and they seem to fit very well. I will provide plots in a few days.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a another approach. 
For convenience I write $n$ instead of $N$, and $A_n$ for $A$.

By definition

$$\det(A_n) = \sum_{\pi\in S_n} \operatorname{sign}(\pi) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\pi(i)}$$

By assumption $A_n$ is symmetric and the $a_{i,j}$ are (for $j\geq i$)  mutually independent random variables $X_{i,j}$
with $\mathbb{E}(X_{i,i})=p=:a$, $\mathbb{E}(X_{i,j})=p^2=:c$, and $\mathbb{E}(X_{i,j}^2)=p^4 +\frac{p^2(1-p^2)}{n}=:b$ for $j\not =i$.

Denote by $C(\pi)$ the set of cycles of $\pi$ and write 
$\prod_{i=1}^n X_{i,\pi(i)}= \prod_{C \in C(\pi)} X_C$, with $X_C:=\prod_{i\in C} X_{i,\pi(i)}$. The cycles are disjoint, thus
the different $X_C$ are independent, further 
$$\mathbb{E}(X_C)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cr} a &\mbox{ if $C$ is a fixed point}\\
 b &\mbox{ if $C$ is a 2-cycle (transposition)}\\
 c^{|C|} &\mbox{ if the length $|C|$ of $C$ is $\geq 3$}\end{array}\right.$$

To use that, denote by $Z_i(\pi), \,1\leq i\leq n$  the no. of cycles of length $i$ of $\pi$ and by $Z(\pi)=\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i(\pi)$
denote the total no. of cycles of $\pi$, and recall that $\operatorname{sign}(\pi)=(-1)^{n-Z(\pi)}$ ( "a permutation $\pi\in S_n$ is even iff 
it's decrement $n-Z(\pi)$ is even"). We then have

$$\mathbb{E}\det(A_n)=\sum_{\pi\in S_n} (-1)^{n-Z(\pi)}  a^{Z_1(\pi)} b^{Z_2(\pi)} c^{n-Z_1(\pi)-2Z_2(\pi)}$$

It is well known how to handle this type of sums. Standard generating function techniques (see e.g. section 5.2 in Stanley's EC 2) show that
$$\sum_{\pi \in S_n} t^{Z(\pi)} t_1^{Z_1(\pi)}\ldots{t_n}^{Z_n(\pi)}=n! [z^n] e^{\sum_{i=1}^n t\,t_i\frac{z^i}{i}}$$
Using that and simple manipulations we find 
$$\mathbb{E}\det(A_n)=n!\,[z^n] (1+cz)\,e^{(a-c)z-(b-c^2)\frac{z^2}{2}}$$
The Hermite polynomials $He_n(x)$ are defined by $He_n(x)=n![t^n] e^{xt-\frac{t^2}{2}}$. Now note that with $v:=b-c^2$ (the variance of the off-diagonal matrix elements)
and $d:=a-c$ (the difference of the expectations) you have
$$\mathbb{E}\det(A_n)=\sqrt{v^n}\,He_n(\frac{d}{\sqrt{v}})+cn\sqrt{v^{n-1}}\,He_{n-1}(\frac{d}{\sqrt{v}})$$

The asymptotic properties of the Hermite polynomials have been intensively investigated, so you can probably find precise results for your concrete setting in the literature.

EDIT: Note that this doesn't answer your question for the expectation of the **absolute value** of the determinant (thanks to Carlo Beenakker for pointing this out). I'll still leave it here in case someone's interested in the expectation of the determinant.

Comment: The OP asks for the expectation value of the _absolute value_ of the determinant. Can your method be applied to that? I noticed that your answer oscillates around zero as a function of $p$ and I'm concerned that the averages of $|\det A|$ and $\det A$ might have different asymptotics.

Comment: You're right, I failed to notice that. I don't think that the expectation of the absolute value of the determinant can be attacked by the same method.
But note that $\mathbb{E}|\det(A)|\geq |\mathbb{E}\det(A)|$ so that the formula gives a lower bound. One might try to compute $\mathbb{E}(\det(A^2)$ in the same way, and use that for an upper bound (since here
$\det(A^2)=|\det(A)|^2$, we have $\big(\mathbb{E}|\det(A)|\big)^2\leq \mathbb{E}\det(A^2)$).

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question here : [Expected value of determinant of simple infinite random matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297155/expected-value-of-determinant-of-simple-infinite-random-matrix/297183#297183)

I rewrite the heuristique from the random matrix theory: 
$$A=p^2 1 + (p-p^2)I_N+\sqrt{p^2(1-p^2)}\tilde{A}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}D$$

where $1$ is the matrix with entries all equal to 1, $D$ a diagonal matrix with bounded variance. And $A$ is a matrix iid random entries with zero mean and variance $1/N$. Therefore its eigenvalues should be distributed similarly as the semicircul law. Because the first matrix is a rank one perturbation and $\| \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}D \|$ is small, we could ignore them at first approximation.
$$\frac{1}{N}\log(|\det(A)|)\sim \frac{1}{N}(\log(|\det(\frac{p-p^2}{\sqrt{p^2(1-p^2)}}I_N+\tilde{A}))|)+\log(\sqrt{p^2(1-p^2)}) $$
We now use the semicircul law and we should get
$$\frac{1}{N}(\log(|\det(\Lambda I_N+\tilde{A})|))=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma (\tilde{A})} \log (|\Lambda+\lambda|) \sim 
\int_{-2}^{2} \log(|\Lambda+\lambda|) \rho(\lambda) d\lambda$$ where $\Lambda=\frac{p-p^2}{\sqrt{p^2(1-p^2)}}$ and $\rho(\lambda ) = \frac{\sqrt{4-\lambda^2}}{2\pi}$ is the semicircul law. 
So finally we should obtain
$$\frac{1}{N}\log(|\det(A)|)\sim \log(\sqrt{p^2(1-p^2)})+\int_{-2}^{2} \log(|\Lambda+\lambda|) \rho(\lambda) d\lambda$$